# Extract TweetID from tweet url in Swift

Tags: swift, regex

I'm trying to use regex to extract the tweet id from a tweet url.

https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1383233200885882885

I want only `"1383233200885882885"`

```swift
let range =  NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count)
let pattern =
"""
(?<=\\/)\\d+(?=(?:\\?.*)?$)
"""
```

I've gotten this far, but I dont know how to use it.

Comment: You may consider [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) to parse your URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id is always at the end you don’t need to use a regex

```
let url = "https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1383233200885882885"

if let lastIndex = url.lastIndex(of: "/") { 
    let id = url.suffix(from: url.index(after: lastIndex))
    print(id)
}
```

An option is to use URLComponents as mentioned in a comments, this will also work if the if the url contains any query items.

```
let components = URLComponents(string: url)
let id = components?.path.split(separator: "/").last
```

Comment: The problem is, there could be something like "?source=facebook" at the end of the URL, right after the tweet ID. Could you edit your answer considering that? So taking until the question mark, or only until numbers end, or something like that...

Comment: @PraveenNagaraj the second alternative works for that

Comment: Oh okay got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
([0-9]+)\/?$
```

Group numbers: **([0-9]+)**

Last "/" (escaped) optional: **\/?**

https://regex101.com/r/90MWRq/1

Edit: added optional querystring, excuse me, but I'm not familiarized  with swift programming language

```
([0-9]+)\/?(?:\?.*)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/GCtIY4/1

Comment: What if the URL was like this https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1383233200885882885?s=20 
Then it doesnt work... Could you also provide the swift syntax on how to use it?

Comment: @PraveenNagaraj added querystring option